# php array combine/merge

Tags: php, arrays

hi to all stackoverflow members, please help me with my problem regarding array manipulation.

```
stores_array:  
Array
(
    [0] => store1
    [1] =>store2
)  

items_array:  
Array  
(  
  [electronics]=>led tv  
  [cosmetics]=>eyeliner  
  [fruits]=>apple 
  [vegetables]=>cabbage  
)
```

here is what i have so far:

```
$new_array = array();
  foreach($stores_array as $t) {
      $new_array[$t] = $items_array;
  }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($new_array);  
    echo '<pre/>';
```

here is the output:

```
Array
(
[store1] => Array
    (
      [electronics]=>led tv  
      [cosmetics]=>eyeliner  
      [fruits]=>apple 
      [vegetables]=>cabbage  
    )  
[store2] => Array
    (
      [electronics]=>led tv  
      [cosmetics]=>eyeliner  
      [fruits]=>apple 
      [vegetables]=>cabbage  
    )

)
```

here is what i want to achieve:
i wanted to add some other values in each of the array.
pls see the arrow i intend to add.

```
Array
(
[store1] => Array
    (
      [electronics]=>led tv  
      [cosmetics]=>eyeliner  
      [fruits]=>apple 
      [vegetables]=>cabbage
      [store]=>store1  <------- how can i add these?
    )  
[store2] => Array
    (
      [electronics]=>led tv  
      [cosmetics]=>eyeliner  
      [fruits]=>apple 
      [vegetables]=>cabbage 
      [store]=>store2  <------- how can i add these?
    )

)
```

thanks you all in advance..

Comment: Isn't that information sort of redundant?

Comment: `foreach ($new_array as $store => $store_info)` will get you that information without wasting memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($stores_array as $t) {
    $new_array[$t] = $items_array;
    $new_array[$t]["store"]=$t;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);  
echo '<pre/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (array_keys($my_array) as $key) {
    $my_array[$key]['store'] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively easy, if I understand the problem.  Try this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($stores_array as $t) {
    $new_array[$t] = $items_array;
    $new_array['store'] = $t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the value at the end in the array.

```
  $new_array = array();

  foreach($stores_array as $t) {
      $items_array[] = $t;
      $new_array[$t] = $items_array;
  }
```

Anyway, if you just want to retrieve the key somehow, you dont need to store it anywhere, you can always access to it using `key($array)`

In your case:

```
foreach($new_array as $data){
    echo key($data);
}
```

You can find more information about the `key` function at [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/function.key.php).

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B said, it is sort of redundant data, but here is my answer:

$new_array = array();

```
foreach($stores_array as $t) {
    $new_array[$t] = $items_array;
    $new_array[$t]['store'] = $t;
}
```